# Error in histogram measurements

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, probability, statistics, correlation-functions

I ran into the following statement [here](http://quantum.ch.ntu.edu.tw/ycclab/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/WHAM_1992.pdf) and [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.1195) but I believe it's more general.

Let's suppose we're running a simulation of a system and we are interested in the distribution of a quantity (say $M$). One would then run the simulation for a long time and construct a histogram of $M$. The counts in the histogram corresponding to a value of $M$ are $N(M)$. One can denote by $\langle N(M) \rangle$ the ensemble average of $N(M)$, over all simulations of a given length. The statement is that the error in the histogram goes like:

$\delta^2N(M) = (1+2 \tau) \langle N(M) \rangle$

Here $\tau$ is the correlation time of the system, or, of the quantity of interest. My first question is, is $\delta^2N(M)$ the variance or the standard deviation from the ensemble average? Second, how would you prove the above relation?

As an example, one could think of a Monte Carlo simulation of an Ising system, trying to obtain a distribution of the magnetization.

Comment: Take a look at Appendix B of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0010-4655(00)00215-0).

Comment: @user8153, almost there. The precise step I need is cited from a paper I have no access to, but it's a good starting point. Thank you.